# ruby shoes convert to hex code from ask_color

Tags: ruby, colors, hex, rgb, shoes

I have tried many times to resolve this problem. Please help me.

I created this code:

```
Shoes.app do
  button "Color" do
    @giv_color=ask_color("Seleziona un colore")
    def rgb(r, g, b)
      "##{to_hex r}#{to_hex g}#{to_hex b}"
    end
    def to_hex(n)
      n.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0').upcase
    end
    para @giv_color # => this give me a result in rgb of a selected color ( es. rgb(20, 20, 40) )
    para rgb(100, 200, 300) #=> this give me a correct hex color convetided
  end
end
```

I'm not understanding why I am not converting the value rgb in hex code automatically.

Comment: This code won't even run because it is missing an `end`. Also `def rgb(r,g,b); end` defines an empty method. Are you sure you know what the problem is?

Comment: Man the problem is not the code because work perfectly, the problem is that i can not convert @giv_color in hex code. Try my code before comment.

Comment: @awar provide an example of a value for `@giv_color` - what it's returning, and what you want it to return. I'm guessing the user selects a from a color picker?

Comment: If i write rgb(40, 30, 80) i can convert, but when i want convert the valute of ask_color it return same value like RGB(...) that i verify from para @giv_color and i can not convert in hex code. The value from two element is same. Why one i can convert and same value from ask_color not?

Comment: We don't know what the methods `ask_color` or `para` do. As such, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Of curse. But in the title there is write Ruby shoes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on its own after several attempts. I did not realize what I was returning from the color selection was a string, clean the latter and converted to integer numbers I have solved the riddle. Thanks for your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
Shoes.app do
  button "Color" do
    @giv_color=ask_color("Seleziona un colore")
  def rgb(r, g, b)
      "#{to_hex r}#{to_hex g}#{to_hex b}"
      end
    def to_hex(n)
       n.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0').upcase
end
  arr = @giv_color.inspect.tr('rgb()','').split(',') # clean string returned from selected color
  a = arr[0].to_i #--|
  b = arr[1].to_i #  | ---- convert the string number on integer
  c = arr[2].to_i #--|

  hex = rgb(a, b, c)
  para hex # <<--- return the hex code
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy way to convert an array of numbers (like [123, 22, 0]) to its hex color code (#7b1600).

```
def rgb array
  "#%02x%02x%02x" % array
end
```

Comment: This is a much simpler and cleaner solution than implenting the code above

Comment: This is realy nice ! Thanks !